# 100% Height In Table In Div

Tags: html, css

I have a table in a div. I need the div to resize with the window, but only the width changes. The div and table are defined as follows:

```
<div id="chatDiv">
    <table align='left' border='1'  id='messagetable'>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
#messagetable {
    width: 99%;
    height: 99%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#chatDiv {
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow;
    width: 99%;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

There is enough text to have the scroll bar appear.

When I change the height to a percent, i.e. to height:100%;, it acts as if the line is not there. What I mean is that the result is the same without the line.

The strange thing is that the width changes. Setting overflow-y:hidden defeats the purpose.

Any ideas? Let me know if I need to clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question? Can you show what you mean?

Comment: why not give the chat div height in percentage ? That will resize it depending on the window size.

Comment: @palerdot I have tried. That is the problem

Comment: can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ? your code shows height in pixels.

Comment: @putvande How do I get the height to resize automatically. Here is the link to my site: http://24.255.213.250:50005/chatbox.html. I set the height to a percent, but it does not work.

Comment: See it solves your problem http://jsfiddle.net/QKMUU/

Comment: @palerdot I am currently using pixels, until I get the percent working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for. Explicitly set the height of the body and set the height of the div back to percentage:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#chatDiv{
    height:100%;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/smtMT/)

Comment: @Sogeking Did you try the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smtMT/)? Does it work there? What is it that you're actually trying to achieve? Do you want the container to be as high and wide as the viewport? Then this should do the trick. Or is it something else?

Comment: It works fine in your example, but not in my code. I replaced the css with the code and your example, but it does not work.

Comment: @Sogeking Is there other CSS involved? Maybe something gets overwritten?

Comment: There is not any other css

Comment: @Sogeking I have checked your URL and it comes to that: You have a `<center>`-tag wrapped around the `#chatDiv`. Then of course this tag must also have set the height explicitly, like `center { height: 100%; }` to get it to work. Also note, that `<center>` is no longer supported in HTML5. That's not an issue, as you use HTML4 as the doctype. But actually you don't need this tag. If you want to center something use CSS and for example `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: @insertuseramehere Thanks. That was the problem